# Messages agent wants to use your confidential information stored in “<key>” in your keychain

Tags: macos, messages, keychain, ichat

After upgradering to Mavericks, I have been bombarded repeatedly with the following prompt:

> Messages agent wants to use your confidential information stored in “” in your keychain
>   [Allow] [Always allow] [Deny]

No matter how many times each option is used, the popup appears again after a very short while (usually less than 15 seconds).

Erasing the Messages.app/iChat-related preference files from `~/Library/Preferences/` did *not* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This fixed it for me (though note the caveat at the bottom)

Open `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app`, search for `message`, which in my case came up with two keys that I deleted. This required Administrator rights, though.

#### iCloud still wonky though

Probably because I trashed some of my preferences. I can live with that for the time being as it is not in my face every ten seconds.